# giving priority to values in an SQL stmt

Tags: sql

is there any way i can do a query to specify that I want to give priority to some value?

for instance i have:

```
SELECT TOP (20) 
  r.MD5, r.Title, r.Link, t.Category, t.tfidf, COUNT(r.MD5) AS matching_terms
FROM 
  Resource AS r INNER JOIN tags AS t ON r.MD5 = t.MD5
WHERE        
  (t.Category IN ('algorithm', 'k-means', 'statistics', 'clustering', 'science'))

GROUP BY r.MD5, r.Title, r.Link, t.Category, t.tfidf
ORDER BY matching_terms DESC, t.tfidf DESC
```

i want that 'algorithm' is given higher priority when finding results. any ideas?

Comment: I guess, giving `'algorithm'` a priority is just an example. Simply ordering by category won't work, if `'k-means'` should become the priority

Comment: @Neil i would order by category, but that would just order them alphabetically no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how high a priority you want to make `'algorithm'`, but in any case, you can add this to the `ORDER BY` clause, in order to make it the most important category (all other categories are equally important):

```
ORDER BY ..., CASE t.Category = 'algorithm' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, ...
```

If however your concept of "priority" is somehow correlated with the importance of the `matching_terms` expression, you could also try something like this (you'd have to nest your above select)

```
SELECT TOP(20) FROM (
  [your original select without TOP(20) clause]
)
ORDER BY (matching_terms * CASE t.Category = 'algorithm' 
                           THEN 1.5 ELSE 1 END) DESC, t.tfidf DESC
```

But that's just an example to give you an idea.

**UPDATE**: Following you comment, you can generate a case statement like this:

```
ORDER BY CASE t.Category WHEN 'algorithm'  THEN 0
                         WHEN 'k-means'    THEN 1
                         WHEN 'statistics' THEN 2
                         WHEN 'clustering' THEN 3
                         WHEN 'science'    THEN 4 END
```

Or alternatively (especially if your list of categories is large), then you should add a `sort` field to tags, containing the priority. Then you could simply order by `sort`

Comment: rather than just have algorithm first, I would like that the order in which i specified the tags in will be the priority in retrieving the results. is this possible?

Comment: is there a way I can limit the amount of websites I get with a tag, for instance..if I only want the top 20, and the first 20 are all algorithm but I still want a mixture for e.g. top 3 of algorithm, top 3 of k-means..if this is possible, it would be really ideal to what I need

Comment: that can be achieved with a `UNION`: `(SELECT TOP(3) .. WHERE Category = 'algorithm') UNION ALL (SELECT TOP(3) .. WHERE Category = 'k-means') ORDER BY ..`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT        TOP (10) r.MD5, r.Title, r.Link, t.Category, t.tfidf, COUNT(r.MD5) AS matching_terms
FROM            Resource AS r INNER JOIN
                         tags AS t ON r.MD5 = t.MD5
WHERE        (t.Category IN ('astrophysics', 'athletics', 'sports', 'football', 'soccer'))
GROUP BY r.MD5, r.Title, r.Link, t.Category, t.tfidf
ORDER BY (CASE t .Category WHEN 'astrophysics' THEN 0 WHEN 'athletics' THEN 1 WHEN 'sports' THEN 2 WHEN 'football' THEN 3 WHEN 'soccer' THEN 4 END)
```

Thanks for giving me the idea Lukas Eder